# load chart.js as user scrolls

Tags: javascript, jquery, canvas, charts

I am using chart.js to make some nice looking canvas charts on a page. I would like the charts to load as the user scrolls  down the page like this example:http://www.chartjs.org

I can not find any information on their site on how they did this. I tried setting it up myself using the waypoints.js as a base. Here is the code I used

```
('.secTwo').waypoint(function(direction) {
$('.hidden').removeClass('hidden');
 });
```

IN my css .hidden is set to opacity:0. This works in that the chart appears as soon as .secTwo hits the top of the window. But the chart doesn't animate like the example above. It simply appears.

The animation only works on page load. I need it work as soon as the chart is visible on screen. Any ideas?

Answer (score 2):

They use a modified version of Remy Sharps jquery plugin that adds triggers an "inview" event when the user scrolls your content into view.

https://github.com/zuk/jquery.inview/

You will have to check the license of the Chart.js modified code before you use it, but their source is available here:

http://www.chartjs.org/assets/effects.js

The plugin allows you to listen for "inview" events triggered when your "down-the-page" content is scrolled into view.

Here's an example:

```
$("#polarAreaChart").on("inview",function(){

    var $this = $(this);

    $this.removeClass("hidden").off("inview");

    setTimeout(showPolarAreaChart,graphInitDelay);          

});
```